# php mysql select statement with Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error but this sql statement works fine in mysql it might be something dumb but im wore out from working on it all weekend.

```
select e.* 
, t.nombre
, c.compania 
, c.nombre 
, c.apellido 
, c.ruc 
, c.direccion 
from envio e 
inner join cliente c on e.cliente_id = c.id 
inner join transporte t on t.id = e.transporte_id 
limit 0, 10;

MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 0, 10' at line 11
```

here's the var_dump result:

```
string(263) "select e.* , t.nombre as transporte_nombre , c.compania , c.nombre , c.apellido , c.ruc , c.direccion from envio e inner join cliente c on e.cliente_id = c.id inner join transporte t on t.id = e.transporte_id limit 0, 10" MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 0, 10' at line 11
```

Here's my code, now I am using 2 classes for this 1 is my db connection which works fine(tested with other pages) and the other is the one that returns the select.

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['page']))
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
else
    $page = "1";

$limit = 10;    
if($page)
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
else
    $start = 0; 

require_once("../class/sql.php");
$db = new MySQL();  

require_once("../class/envios.php");
$envios = new Envio();
var_dump($envios->BuscaEnvios("",$start,$limit));

if(is_array($conditions))
    $consulta = $db->consulta($envios->BuscaEnvios($conditions,$start,$limit));  
else
    $consulta = $db->consulta($envios->BuscaEnvios("",$start,$limit));  

if($db->num_rows($consulta) > 0)
    $total_pages = $db->num_rows($consulta);
else 
    $total_pages = 0;
```

In class "Envios":

```
public function BuscaEnvios($conditions, $start, $limit)
{
        $sql = "select 
              e.*
            , t.nombre as transporte_nombre 
            , c.compania
            , c.nombre
            , c.apellido
            , c.ruc
            , c.direccion
        from envio e 
        inner join cliente c on e.cliente_id = c.id
        inner join transporte t on t.id = e.transporte_id ";

        if($conditions != "")
            $sql .= ' where '. implode(' AND ', $conditions);

        $sql .= " limit $start, $limit";

        return $sql;

}
```

Comment: limit 0, 10 is basically saying "return 0 rows, starting at line 10".  I think you want them the other way around?

Comment: @GordonM that's not correct, 0 (start), 10 (rows).

Comment: @GordonM the syntax is read as `limit 10 offset 0`;

Comment: when i put this same statement as is in mysql through phpadmin it shows 10 records 0-9 but i switched it around and still no difference :(

Comment: @Andreas Can you use PHP to var_dump the sql? I suspect is some sort of whitespaces

Comment: @ajreal: That's the metnod I prefer, but `LIMIT 10, 0` should also be valid.  `LIMIT 0, 10`, however, probably isn't because it's saying "return 0 rows"

Comment: @Prisoner it shows fine inside phpadmin I get that error when running on my php page

Comment: @GordonM, no it isnt: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: @ajreal how do I use var_dump? thats new to me

Comment: @Andres if the problem is in the PHP then post the PHP - there is nothing wrong with the query (it displays fine in PHPMyAdmin) so post some code.

Comment: @Prisoner ok let me post some code

Comment: Just out of interest, please will you try changing `LIMIT 0,10` to `LIMIT 10`? This should still have the same effect...

Comment: @DaveRandom ok let me try that but the idea is that I am using a php paging so I will need the start, limit so the paging can work, but i can try it now to see if there is an issue there....that didn't make difference

Comment: is any variable you have used to hold the query i. e. ( $que = your query) and than you are passing that var as mysql_query($que);

Comment: $db->num_rows($consulta) that queries the statement.  And I tried passing just this line: $consulta = $db->consulta($envios->BuscaEnvios("",$start,$limit)); and it show data...

Comment: is that error coming even if the conditions are not their?, and one more thing please improve your **if** conditions in the function **bound the output of if with {}**

Comment: yes, the only time it doesn't show the error is when I take this line completely out if(is_array($conditions))
    $consulta = $db->consulta($envios->BuscaEnvios($conditions,$start,$limit));

Comment: it means some where the conditions are breaking the code, just for debug put your conditions and print inside the function print_r($conditions); see what you will get as output.

Comment: the print_r($conditions) return Array ( )

Comment: just try with my given code in answer. see if it's working?

Comment: @punit your code did it, but I can't mark it as answered cause it was deleted?

Comment: i was deleted because some people started down voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code in your function

```
if(sizeof($conditions)>0)
          {
            $sql .= " where ".implode(' AND ', $conditions);
          }

        $sql .= " limit $start, $limit";
```

Comment: This worked but I used the sizeof($condition) before calling the function.  So when I go to that function I just check if $condition != ""  :)

thanks everybody because every comment got me 1 step closer to fixing it!

Comment: @Andres if condition is an array, why not just saying `if (count($conditions))`?

Comment: -1 for ugly limit offset usage, would not this `limit $limit offset $start` make more sense? (and is standard SQL)

Comment: I guess that would work too @Mario just that I needed to finish this and this was the first thing I tried after spending hours working on it.  Thanks anyways.  And the limit $start, $limit I got that because my pagination code uses it that way and I think Punit was just copying what I had, no real reason to downvote.